# How do you evaluate a string as a clojure expression?

Tags: clojure, eval, metaprogramming, evaluation

How would I get something similar to the following?:

```
(evaluate-text "(+ 1 2)")  ; resolves to 3
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
(load-string "(+ 1 2)")
```

Answer (score 31):

```
user> (eval (read-string "(+ 1 2)"))
3
```

You probably shouldn't ever need to do this.  Macros and fns make this kind of thing unnecessary 99% of the time.  This is quite brittle, and can be unsafe if these strings are coming from user input, and so on.

Comment: Well I want to do something radically unsafe: a REPL chatbot.

Comment: There is a clojurebot in #clojure.

Comment: load-string does exactly what he is looking for

Comment: you need it if you are saving Clojure data structures to a file for storage and then later restoring them, for example.

Comment: In ClojureScript `read-string` is in the `cljs.reader/read-string` namespace, not `core` like in Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

How similar does it have to be?  Clojure's `eval` works on lists, so:

```
(eval (list + 1 2)) #=> 3
```

Comment: I know about eval, but I don't think it works for me.  I really want to evaluate a "String"