# Clojure "eval" unable to evaluate!

Tags: java, programming-languages, clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you evaluate a string as a clojure expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885448/how-do-you-evaluate-a-string-as-a-clojure-expression)

Getting data from a JTextField/Area (from Java Application) returns the data of class **java.lang.String**. passing this data to **eval** of **Clojure** isn't evaluating it, instead printing as such because it is a string. How to make **eval** evaluate this data and return output.

e.g.) **Assume data in text-field is (+ 2 3)**

`(println (eval (.getText text-field) ))`

[image]This prints **(+ 2 3)** instead of **5**

Comment: Yeah thats a duplicate. I should have checked that before posting answer :)

Comment: @sepp2k not only string but all type of data which can be returned by Java app. But Duplicate also solves my problem!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a Clojure data structure before it can be eval'd, since [eval](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/eval) expects a valid form data structure as per the docs:

```
(doc eval)
-------------------------
clojure.core/eval
([form])
  Evaluates the form data structure (not text!) and returns the result.
```

The easiest way of doing this is to use [read-string](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read-string) on your String, e.g.

```
(eval (read-string "(+ 2 7)"))
=> 9
```

Comment: read-string is the 'R' part of REPL

Answer (score 4):

You will have to convert the string `"(+ 2 3)"` to List data structure i.e `(list + 2 3)` or `'(+  2 3)` and then pass it to eval to evaluate the form. A string is evaluated to a string hence you get `"(+ 2 3)"` after evaling the string `"(+ 2 3)"`

Ex:

```
(eval (read (new java.io.PushbackReader (new java.io.StringReader "(+ 1 2)"))))
```

Read is the "Reader" which read a stream and parses it into clojure code which is then evaluated using eval

Comment: You can just use `read-string` instead of using `read` with the reader objects.